# How to add Placeholder text in fields with django crispy-forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm new to django and using crispy-forms to render the form.How do i add placeholder text to a field e.g "please enter your address"

In my views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = Post 
    fields = ['name', 'address']
```

In models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank="true")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank="true")
```

Comment: can you share your html?

Answer (score 0):

Every input field is Given an id by django; get the ids from inspect -- In the Html file and add a script tag some where and
Then use this JS code

```
document.getElementbyId('id of the field').setAtribute('placeholder','Your PH')
```

Btw use google for spelling errors and soory for them